# Colocating Assets and Posts in Astro

Tags: javascript, astrojs

Is there any way to colocate markdown files and the assets referenced in those markdown files in a single folder in astro.

What i am looking for is to have a sirectory structure similar to the following:

```
src/
    posts/
        post1/
            post1.mdx
            image1-in-post1.png
            image2-in-post1.png
            ...
```

This is instead of locating the assets in the **public** directory and needing to consistently reference back to them.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Astro does not currently support this type of directory structure. You would need to either store your assets in the public directory and reference them from there or use a third-party service such as Cloudinary to store and manage your assets.